# Spring 2.0.0-RELEASE ConfigurationProperties binding does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This scenario was ok in 1.5.3.RELEASE.

I have external property file external.yml it look like this

```
app:
  datasources:
    - name: sourceOne
      driver: xxx
      url: some_url
      username: u1
      password: p1
    - name: sourceTwo
      driver: xxx
      url: some_url2
      username: u2
      password: p2
```

i have added `@EnableConfigurationProperties({DatabaseProperties.class})`

The class looks like:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:database.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app") // prefix app, find app.* values
public class DatabaseProperties {
private List<DataSourceFromProperties> datasources;
// getter and setters
```

when i am starting application this error was thrown:

```
    Failed to bind properties under 'app' to ...DatabaseProperties:

        Property: app
        Value: 
        Origin: "app" from property source "class path resource [database.yml]"
        Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties ...DatabaseProperties]

    Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

it seems like binding is changed in 2.0.0-RELEASE

Any idea what should i update/change in this scenario?

here is the pom file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add this dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: still the same  No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties

Comment: Do you happen to have `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` defined?

Comment: Dont have ConversionServiceFactoryBean, should i have?

Comment: No, that was marked as an issue in some forum I read. I wouldn't know without more information

Comment: `@PropertyScource` is only for property files not for YAML files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this in this way:

1. PropertyScource is only for .properties files so i change .yml to .properties

   app.datasources[0].name=aaa
   app.datasources[0].driver=aaa
   app.datasources[0].url=aaa
   app.datasources[0].username=aaa
   app.datasources[0].password=aaa

   app.datasources[1].name=bbb
   app.datasources[1].driver=bbb
   app.datasources[1].url=bbb
   app.datasources[1].username=bbb
   app.datasources[1].password=bbb

The problem was in DatabaseProperties

the inner class MUST be static

```
public class  DatabaseProperties{
private List<InnerClass> datasources;
public List<InnerClass> getDatasources() {
        return datasources;
}
.
.
.
static class InnerClass{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySource` does not support YAML files out of the box.

Marten Deinum put together [a really great article](https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/) demonstrating how to add YAML support. Here's a shortened version of his example for brevity:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        Properties propertiesFromYaml = factory.getObject();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(name, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

}
```

Refer to his article for a more complete code example.